# How to clear margin from input (bootstrap)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I clear the right side margin from an input? I have tried `m-auto`, `clear:both` but these didn't work.

code:

`<ul class="list-inline">
  <li class="list-inline-item"><input type="text" class="form-control w-50"></li>
  <li class="list-inline-item"><input type="text" class="form-control"></li>
</ul>`

https://jsfiddle.net/rnxbfm0j/1/
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjW5f.png)

Comment: Have you tried using, say, CSS? `margin-right: 0`?

Comment: yes `marina-right:0px !important`, not worked.

Comment: Well, no, `marina-right` wouldn't work, because it's `margin-right`. Spelling matters in programming.

Comment: I am sorry its just typo here, i tried `margin-right`

Comment: [Edit] your question to include a [mre]. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to include a runnable example of how it doesn't work. You can use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>` in the HTML section to include Bootstrap.

Comment: Yes, will update soon, thanks for improvements

Comment: Try removing `w-50` in the html on your input class.

Comment: thanks @bron, you gave me hint, i just set width to input in px value and issue solved!

Answer (score 0):

I just set width(px) to class form-control and its solved.